# Can't access wp-admin after http to https change

Tags: wp-admin, https

Changed to url from http to https in settings >> general. Hit save changes. Now I get this error:

```
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Additionally I can now not access the wp-admin login anymore. And all the tips I've found online says you can fix this via de c-panel of phpMyAdmin, but I do not have access to this either. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This likely requires Apache/Nginx or other server level changes judging from the kind of error message you're recieving. That message is not something WordPress is generating, it's much more likely to be an Apache/Nginx misconfiguration

Comment: If you have FTP access it may be worth looking what you have in the .htaccess file. If you don't have access to a hosting control panel but do have the database user credentials you may use a stand-alone MySQL client to access the database and at least change the wp_options settings back to the non-https address.

Comment: Fixed it via FTP! Question closed.